# How to get the value of colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried different jQuery approaches:

```
var num = $(this).attr('colspan').text();
var num = $(this).attr('colspan').val();
var num = $(this).('td[colspan]').val();
var num = $(this).('td[colspan]').text();
var num = $(this).('td[colspan]').attr('id');
```

and this from W3Schools: `var num = document.getElementById($(this)).colSpan;`

no luck. It's either undefined or an uncaught TypeError in my `console.log()`

---

EDIT:
I have tried your suggestions and it still isn't working. Here is part of the code in context:

```
$('table td').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
    var th, index, id, td;
    if(e.type === 'mouseenter'){
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        td = $(this);
        var num = $(this).attr('colspan');
        console.log("td = "+td+" colspan = "+num);
        td.addClass('highlight');

var $table_body_scroll=$('table.body_scroll'),
            header_table=$( '<table aria-hidden="true" class="header_table"><thead><tr><td></td></tr></thead></table>' ),
            scroll_div='<div class="body_scroll"></div>';
        var $targetHeaderTable=$("table.header_table").eq(index);

        $('thead tr th').each(function() {
            console.log("th = "+$(this).text());
            console.log("id = "+id);
            if ($(this).text() == id)
            {
                var num = td.attr('colspan');
                //console.log("td = "+td+" colspan = "+num);
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
            }
        });

        index = $('td').index($(e.target));
        $(e.target).prevAll().addClass('highlight');

    }else{
        $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

and my console log: `td = [object Object] colspan = undefined`

Comment: Try this: `var num = $(this).attr('colspan')`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A283U/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `prop` to get the value set for the attribute/property, this will reflect any changes made to the property with JS after the page load:

```
$(this).prop("colSpan");
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9u8L2/1

Comment: @user2690363 Is that code complete?  The `on` function is not properly closed, is that just a mistake in the question?

Comment: the property is called `colSpan` not `colspan`

Comment: That was just part of it. I made another edit to add the entire thing.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't agree with that can you point me to a source?  MDN says: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Comment: I used your `.prop()` instead and it worked! I was going by the other answer which suggested `.attr()`. Thanks so much.

Comment: @KevinBowersox see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/82W3Y/1/ ... I think jQuery handles it.. but actual dom element reference does not

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for the example, I just noticed they camel cased in jQuery documentation also.

Answer (score 0):

if `this` refers to the td element then

```
var span  = $(this).prop('colSpan')//or
var span  = $(this).attr('colspan')
```